# Postgresql query returns string values between quotation marks " if it contains any space character or without quotation if it had no space char

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, psql, php-pgsql

so I got this strange issue and I have no idea what's causing it. We are using Charts.js in PHP to plot some charts. We store the arguments needed to create a chart into a PSQL table to load when needed.

My issue lies with the title, group and label parameters which are all string arrays. They are stored in a text[] table. The issue is, when I query a graph's parameter, if a string in the array has any space, it is returned between quotation marks if not it is returned as the string itself.

I have an associative array $graph which stores the graph's parameters and is used to insert the values into the database:

```
$cursor = $this->query("
        INSERT INTO data.graphs(region,title,type,section,label,group,values,colors,id_sample)                   
        VALUES(
            '".$graph['local']."',
            '".$graph['title']."',
            '".$graph['type']."',
            '".$graph['section']."',
            '".$graph['label']."',
            '".$graph['group']."',
            '".$graph['values']."',
            '".$graph['colors']."',
            '".$_SESSION['id_sample']."'
        )  
    ");
```

The string arrays inserted into the DB are like this:

```
$graph1['label'] = "{Não há material presente,Material presente, mas crianças não usaram,Crianças usaram os materiais}";
$graph2['label'] = "{Boa vista, Rural, Urbana, Indigena}";
$graph3['label'] = "{Boa vista, Ru ral, Urb ana, Ind igena}";
```

If I query my labels in the database they look like this:

[image]

Now to query the data we do a 'SELECT *' for the parameters of each graph needed and store they values associative array again (used as parameter for the Charts.js plotter).

```
$aux = pg_fetch_array($cursor))
print_r($aux['label']);
```

This is how my labels look like for each of my 3 graphs:

```
{"Não há material presente","Material presente, mas crianças não usaram","Crianças usaram os materiais"}
{"Boa vista",Urbana,Rural,Indigena}
{"Boa vista","Urb ana","Ru ral","Ind igena"}
```

So in the DB the strings have no quotations and if a qstring has a space it is returned between quotation marks which isn't all bad because I want my string in quotation marks.

Is there any way to force each string returned in the array to be inside all quotation marks?

I already tried inserting into the DB an array like this:

```
$graph['label'] = "{
        \"Boa vista\",
        \"Urbana\",
        \"Rural\",
        \"Indigena\"
    }";
```

If I look into the DB the strings have no quotation, they are returned just like above yet again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default `text` output for type `text[]`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO)

> The array output routine will put double quotes around element values
>   if they are empty strings, contain curly braces, delimiter characters,
>   double quotes, backslashes, or white space, or match the word `NULL`.
>   Double quotes and backslashes embedded in element values will be
>   backslash-escaped.
>   [...] for textual data types one should be prepared to cope with either the presence or absence of quotes.

If you prefer a text representation with all elements double quoted, you could use a simple expression like:

```
SELECT '"' || array_to_string('{"Boa vista",Urbana,Rural,Indigena}'::text[], '", "') || '"'
```

If you need it a lot, consider a (simplistic) function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_to_string_with_quotes(_arr text[], _quote text = '"')
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT $2 || array_to_string($1, $2 || ', ' || $2) || $2
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_array_to_string_with_quotes('{"Boa vista",Urbana,Rural,Indigena}', '"');
```

```
| f_array_to_string_with_quotes              |
| :----------------------------------------- |
| "Boa vista", "Urbana", "Rural", "Indigena" |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cb87d687a779544bc7119079b6e92038)* - with more examples

**Note** that the resulting type is now `text`, not `text[]`! And it does not properly escape anything, hence "simplistic".